# Getting root node's attributes (namespace) in Python

Tags: python, xml, xml-namespaces

I need to extract namespace which comes at the very beginning of xml file.

It looks something like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns:a="CannotGetThisAttrib" xmlns:b="CannotGetThisAttrib">
<fileHeader c="CanGetThisAttrib/>>
<body></body>
<fooder/>
</root>
```

I can extract attributes beneath the root node. However, I cannot get the root node attributes, both a and b, which are namespaces necessary to parse xml file.

```
tree = ET.parse("xmlfile.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
root.attrib => None
root[0].attrib["c"] => CanGetThisAttrib
```

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Is this the built-in ElementTree or is this from the `lxml` module? Also, please fix the syntax errors in your sample XML.

Comment: That being said, what is your overall goal/what issue are you trying to solve?

Comment: I'm using built-in xml modele. And I'm trying to get namespace of root tag's attribute. I can't get it with xml built-in module

Comment: No, that's not what you are actually trying to do. *Why* are you trying to get the namespaces?

Comment: Because I need it to get particular tag beneath the root  tag. Every tag has different kinds of namespace prepended before each tag name

Comment: Namespaces are meant to be hard coded in your Python code. They are not meant to be read from the XML file. You know the namespace URI ahead of time, don't you?

Comment: Like this: `root.findall(".//{http://your/namespace/uri/}tag")` - There are very few situations when you as the developer don't know the namespace URI of the elements you expect to deal with. For example when working with SOAP: `root.find(".//{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}body")`

Answer (score 0):

Here (using lxml)

```
from lxml import etree

data = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
           <root xmlns:a="CannotGetThisAttrib" xmlns:b="CannotGetThisAttrib">
            <fileHeader c="CanGetThisAttrib"/>
            <body></body>
            <fooder/>
         </root>
    '''

data = data.encode('ascii')
tree = etree.fromstring(data)
for k,v in tree.nsmap.items():
    print('{} -> {}'.format(k,v))
```

output

```
a -> CannotGetThisAttrib
b -> CannotGetThisAttrib
```

Comment: I doubt the OP is using lxml.